# Invoking command line programs by double clicking on files in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, netbeans, mingw

I've written a command line program using c++ in the netbeans IDE, then compiled it using mingw.  The program takes as its only argument the name of a file (with the fairly unique extension .mmf) , then it plays a movie based on the file.

What I would like is to be able to set the default application for the .mmf extension to my command line program, so that when I double click on a file of this type, it plays my movie.  When you open a file in windows like this, does it just call your application with the filename as an argument?  Are other arguments passed?

In other words, if I associate the .mmf file type with myprogram.exe, is double clicking on myfile.mmf equivalent to invoking the shell command

```
myprogram myfile.mmf
```

If not, what shell command is invoked?  Also, is the full path to the file passed, or the relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you open a file in windows like this, does it just call your application with the filename as an argument?**

Yes.